# Proof of $P(X<Y)$

Tags: probability, density-function, exponential-distribution

Assume that $X$ is $Exp(\lambda)$ distributed and $Y$ is $Exp(\mu)$, and they are independent. I want to know how I can calculate $P(X<Y)$. I don't understand why

$$ P(X < Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X<Y|X=x)\cdot f_X(x)dx, $$

where $f_X$ is the density of $X$.

Comment: This is the law of total probability.  Essentially, what you are doing is breaking things down by cases of $X$: For all possible values of $X$, what is the joint probability that $X$ holds that value *and* that $Y < X$?  The only wrinkle is that for continuous distributions of $X$, we can't just do ordinary addition, like we would for discrete distributions; we have to integrate.  But otherwise, it's the same basic idea.

Comment: Are you familiar with conditional expectation?

Comment: I know the law of total probability and it helps to understand, but i don't think it's enough to proof it. And yes i learned something conditional expectation.

Comment: You can prove that $$ P(X < Y)=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^y  f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy $$ and use that X,Y are independent and so $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, but the easiest way is the law of total probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent with pdfs $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ we 
have
\begin{align}
P\{X<Y\}&=\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{x=-\infty}^{y}f_X(x)dx\right)f_Y(y)dy\\
&=\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}F_X(y)f_Y(y)dy
\end{align}
where $F_X(x)$ is the CDF of $X$.